# How do I make a table border invisible in the header section of a new ASP.Net MVC 3 app?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I open _Layout.cshtml in a new blank ASP.Net MVC 3 application (using the Intranet Application project template). I replace the header tag and it's contents with this html table:

```
<table style="border-width: 0px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Why is the table border white?
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I run the app and find the table border is not invisible, it's white. Why? **How do I make an invisible html table border in _Layout.cshtml?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is picking up css style (table td) from /Content/Site.css

Try removing border attribute from this css class!

Comment: That's it! The table td style in Site.css overrode my inline table style. Since I didn't add an inline td style the Site.css td style was applied causing my inline table style to be ignored. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about `border-style:none;`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there is css specified within the default style sheet of your project. Take a look at /Content/yourstylesheet.css and look for the rule that is making your table border white.

Or

A simpler way would be to use a tool like firebug or chromes dev tools and inspect the table to see where the css rule is being applied from.